# drone.io Not using .drone.yml file of GitHub repo

Tags: go, drone.io

I have a problem with the CI tool drone. At the Moment I'm using drone.io and with the selft-hosted version I have the same issue. When I try to build my golang test application drone.io always ignores my .drone.yml file.

The GitHub repo is: https://github.com/norbell/dronetest

My .drone.yml file looks like this:

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: golang:1.6
    commands:
      - go get
      - go build
```

And the settings page of my drone.io project looks like this:

[image]

And when I click the build button it shows me that the project was successfully "build":

[image]

Obviously does everything but not building my project. I have done everything I found in the documentation but I can't get it working.

When I put `go get` and `go build` or `go run main.go` into the "commands" textarea field of the settings page, drone is suddenly able to build my go application.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so it would be very nice if someone could help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

https://drone.io/ - doesn't support `.drone.yml` file, this file supported by https://github.com/drone/drone

Comment: to expand on this answer, the .drone.yml is used by the open source version of drone found at github.com/drone/drone. The open source version of drone is not yet powering the drone.io service. This is planned, but not until the open source project reaches a stable 1.0

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a .drone.yml you are forced to host drone on your own.

Comment: But this is a correct answer, drone.io doesn't support the drone.yml, it's only supported by the self-hosted open source version of drone. So he's forced to host drone on his own.